# Added icons in manifest.json but got no icon in splash screen

Tags: android, google-chrome

My demo is not finished yet but you can find it here:
https://frp.im/dev/timedrops/target/

```
{
  "short_name": "Timedrops",
  "name": "Timedrops",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "drop-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "drop-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "index.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "portrait",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8",
  "background_color": "#3E4EB8"

}
```

I followed the steps of creating progressive web apps and tried to add a splash screen first, but failed to display my icon. I also checked HTTPS, still not working in HTTPS. I went though some examples and my JSON is almost right. Why I can't see my icons?

Answer (score 2):

Searched several posts and digged some docs, seems I need a 192x192 icon... Why it doesn't throw warnings...

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/splashscreen

Answer (score 1):

Along with `jiyinyiyon`'s answer, not only does the icon need to be `192x192`, be sure to add the following `link` tag to the HTML `head`:

`<link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="img/icon.png">`

Here's a look at the corresponding `manifest.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "APP - My PWA",
    "short_name": "APP",
    "start_url": "/",
    "scope": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "theme_color": "#95f442",
    "background_color": "#EEE",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "img/icon.png",
            "size": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

The path the the icon image (if not absolute) will be relative to the `start_url`.